# Implements function in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Hey guys luckily I've managed to install mono for android. I was trying to create a button that will show a toast once click. However, it seems that C# has no implements function.

How can you define this in C#?

```
public class helloworld extends Activity implements OnclickListener{


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You implement an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) using the same syntax you'd use to extend a class:

```
public class helloworld : Activity, OnclickListener
{

}
```

Just be sure to list the class that you're inheriting from [before](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_17.1.2_Class_base_specification) interfaces that you're implementing.

Comment: You can declare **one** class that you're **inheriting** from (equivalent to the `extends` keyword in Java).  The remaining declarations must be interfaces.